# Powershell sql query with logic inside cron job

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell, cron

I am trying to move a simple sql query to a cron job. The query gets some data from the database and I want the cron job to update me every 5 minutes on the result.

The thing is, I know how to create a query + I know how to create a simple cron job, but I don't know how to combine the query with the `command` in a cron job.

**Also** I would like to do **some logic** on the query - say if the result is above X, then I would like to use the ILogger interface, to log / notify me about the result.

I don't have much experience in working with the command line as I always place my logic inside a class in a project - solution, and thought maybe a powershell command inside the `command` field would be a solution?

My cron job is as the following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: sqlquery
  labels:
    job-name: sqlquery
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" # every 5 min
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 120
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:         
        metadata:
          name: sqlquery
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: sqlquery
            image: myregistry/sqlquery
            command: $mysql -u myuser -p mypassword -e 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Baseballplayers]
                    WHERE [Age] = [Senior]
                    AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETUTCDATE
                    GROUP BY [Baseballid]
                    ORDER BY [TeamRank] DESC' MyDatabase
                    # I would like to somehow run the sql query - and do some logic on the result.
                    # All of this inside the cron job, if possible.
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shell script e.g. `test.sh` that will contain `mysql query`.

```
output=$(mysql -u myuser -p mypassword -e 'query')
```

Then use the variable `output` for further processing.

And to put the shell script in `Cron Job` use the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

Add new entry

```
*  *  *  *  *  sh path/test.sh  &> path/test.out
```

Here `*  *  *   *   *` denotes `MIN HOUR DayOfMonth MonthOfYear DayOfWeek` respectively.